# Get a structure in C

Tags: c, structure

I developed a code which returns a 30 data :

```
int data1;
int data2;
int data3;
...
float datan;
 ...
float datam;
```

All data have the same type except two. And i want to get all this data at the same time. 
My solution is to collect all this data in structure but it is not elegant.
Have you an other solution?

Comment: You can use Array of integers..

Comment: But array contains the same type. But in my case, i have 2 types int and float.

Comment: No, just internal data (public and global)

Comment: In what way is it not elegant?  Using a struct seems fine to me.

Answer (score 6):

what about someting like:

```
struct Mydata{
    int iElements[<nofintegers>];
    float fElements[<nOfFloats>];
}
```

if you are feeding the structure from some byte buffer in memory, remember to check how your compiler pack the structures. Maybe some undesired extra bytes are added. In any case the compiler should provide some method to override that.

Comment: It is like my last solution but the interface of the code provides the items in the same order as listed in the 1st message.
My solution was :

     struct Mydata{
        int iElements1[<nofintegers>];
        float fElements1[<nOfFloats>];
        int iElements2[<nofintegers>];
        float fElements2[<nOfFloats>];
      }

because i must respect the order.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unions

```
union data{
    int i;
    float f;
}

data my_data_array[30];
```

will do the trick. But reaching values will not be as smooth as an homogeneous array.